# Trouble Arrays and '.class' expected error

Tags: java, arrays, expected-exception

Java.

So basically I'm having issues with the return in 'createWarehouses' array. Either I get a `.class expected error` if I `return w[]` or if I `return w` I get a mismatch error:

> "array required but warehouse found"

for all the public variables that call `createWarehouses`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you prefer, the code is also here:

http://pastebin.com/sAeFZu7M

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WarehouseTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String dataArray[][] = {{ "2200", "10", "5", "5", "200", "First Street",     "Dallas", "Texas", "76000" },
                    { "5550", "12.75", "2", "3", "15", "Mitchell Drive",     "Arlington", "Texas", "76019" },
                    { "12000", "17.5", "6", "7", "0", "Jones Blvd",     "Burleson", "Texas", "76120" },
                    { "7235", "22.35", "54", "80", "30", "Smith Circle",     "Keller", "Texas", "75020" }};

        Warehouse wArray[] = new Warehouse[4];
        wArray = createWarehouses( dataArray ); //15

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, purchaseItems( wArray ));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, printWarehouses( wArray ));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, printWarehouseCharge( wArray ));
    }

    public static Warehouse[] createWarehouses( String dataArray[][] )
    {
        Warehouse w[] = new Warehouse[dataArray.length];

        for( int i = 0; i < w.length; i++ )
        {
            w[i] = new Warehouse( Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][0]),        
                                  Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][1]),
                                  Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i][2]),
                                  Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i][3]),
                                  Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i][4]),
                                  new Address( dataArray[i][5],
                                          dataArray[i][6], dataArray[i][7],     
                                          Integer.parseInt( dataArray[i][8] )));
        }   
        return w[]; // ****<--- THIS IS PROBLEM**strong text**
    }

    public static String printWarehouses( Warehouse w[] )
    {
        String printMsg = String.format("");        

        for( int i = 1; i < w.length; i++ )
        {
            printMsg += String.format( 
            "Square Foot Size %.2f Price Per Square Foot %s Televisions %d     Computers %d Tablets %d %s", 
            Double.parseDouble( w[i][0] ), Double.parseDouble( w[i][1] ), 
            Int.parseInt( w[i][2] ), Int.parseInt( w[i][3] ), Int.parseInt( w[i]    [4] ),
            w[i][5].toString );      
        }               
        return printMsg;
    }

    public static String printWarehouseCharge( Warehouse w[] )
    {
        String chgMsg = String.format("");      

        for( int i = 1; i < w.length; i++ )
        {
            chgMsg += String.format( "$%,.2f\n", w[i].calculateWarehouseCharge()     + w[i].calculateTax() );
        }
        return chgMsg;
    }

    public static String purchaseItems( Warehouse w[] )
    {
        String p[][] = 
                {
                    {"Dallas", "1", "2", "5"}, 
                    {"Arlington", "0", "0", "15"},
                    {"Burleson", "0", "0", "3"},
                    {"Keller", "10", "25", "0"},
                    {"Dallas", "5", "0", "0"},
                    {"Arlington", "0", "1", "0"},
                    {"Burleson", "2", "4", "0"},
                    {"Keller", "0", "30", "3"}
                };

        String msg = String.format("");

        for ( int i = 0; i < w.length; i++ )
        {
            if ( w[i].getAddress().getCity().equals( p[i][0] ))
            {
                msg += String.format("%,.2f\n", w[i].purchaseTelevision(     599, Integer.parseInt( p[i][1] ))
                    + w[i].purchaseComputer( 759, w[i].Integer.parseInt(     p[i][2] ))
                    + w[i].purchaseTablet( 239.99,     w[i].Integer.parseInt( p[i][3] )));
            }   
            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the language you're using.

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: I took your code and there were syntax errors everywhere but where your arrow was. Scratch the code and start writing it again, compiling one method at a time.

Comment: I have compiled one method at a time, I don't get any syntax errors except when calling other methods (obviously because they aren't there). The only consistent syntax error is in the one described in the description.

Comment: Why the hell one does not simply attach stacktrace?

Comment: I'm in a beginner Java course, I don't know what stacktrace is. Do you have a link that might enlighten me? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In your `purchasedItem()`, the `return` should go on the outside of the loop.

Comment: Can you also put the implentation of Wharehouse here in the question? They are to closely related to left out...

Comment: You should `return w` and compile again and see what happens. That's the only thing I see wrong with code, given the error message.

Comment: yes, I will update with the other classes when I get home, I should have included them as well.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you're mistaking errors.  Your `createWarehouses()` method should return an array. When you try and return `w[]`, `w[]` is of `Warehouse` type, that's why you get the error message **"array required but warehouse found"**.

When you change the `w[]` to `w`, which is the correct return type, you may think you're getting the same error message, when actuality, the message is coming from below in another method, the `purchasedItems()` method. In that method, you're trying to return from inside of the loop. That's a compile error also. *See my code at the bottom for fix.*

In your `purchasedItem()`, the `return` should go on the outside of the loop.

You should also make sure to `return w` in the `createWarehouses()`.

With `purchasedItems()`, you should concatenate the entire string with `\n`s instead of trying to return multiple times

```
public static String purchaseItems( Warehouse w[] )
{
    String p[][] = 
            {
                {"Dallas", "1", "2", "5"}, 
                {"Arlington", "0", "0", "15"},
                {"Burleson", "0", "0", "3"},
                {"Keller", "10", "25", "0"},
                {"Dallas", "5", "0", "0"},
                {"Arlington", "0", "1", "0"},
                {"Burleson", "2", "4", "0"},
                {"Keller", "0", "30", "3"}
            };

    String msg = String.format("");

    for ( int i = 0; i < w.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( w[i].getAddress().getCity().equals( p[i][0] ))
        {
            msg += String.format("%,.2f\n", w[i].purchaseTelevision(     599, Integer.parseInt( p[i][1] ))
                + w[i].purchaseComputer( 759, w[i].Integer.parseInt(     p[i][2] ))
                + w[i].purchaseTablet( 239.99,     w[i].Integer.parseInt( p[i][3] )));
        }   
        msg += "\n";
    }
    return msg;
}
```

**Edit: Maybeees**

Maybe in your `printWarehouse()` method, you want something like this instead, because `w[][]` is inaccessible

```
// this is what you have
Double.parseDouble( w[i][0] )

// try this
wArray[i].getSquareFoot();  // or whatever method you use from Warehouse to 
                            // get the square foot from your warehouse class
```

Anywhere outside of the `createWarehouse()` method you are tyring to access `w[i].something`, change it to `wArray[i].something`.  `wArray[]` is the global variable. `w[]` is only accible locally within the `createWarehouse()` method. Remember that.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try as soon as I get home.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but I still have the exact same issue, when I use 'return w;' it gives me a "array required but warehouse found" error in all the strings that call w[]. Whereas if I use 'return w[];' I get the same '.class. expected error.

Comment: Give me an example of which line you're talking about for this error "array required but warehouse found" error in all the strings that call w[]."

Comment: 1. w[] is only accessible from within the `createWarehouse()` method. 2. You're trying to access a 2D `w[i][3]` when a 2D `w[][]` doesn't exist.